How can I get the title in tcolorbox partly framed and not framed?
So, I'm trying to make a box with the tcolorbox package that has some of the title in a colored box and some of it not inside the box. What I want is for the definition X.Y part of the title to be boxed, and the name of the definition/ theorem to not be boxed. It's much easier to see what I'm talking about in a picture, so I made these quickly using paint.net:
Box without title:

Box with title:

So the important thing is that the "Homeomorphisms" part is over the frame and the frame is not visible there.
Here is what I have so far (MWE):
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}

% Defining counter:
\newcounter{defcounter}[chapter] 
\setcounter{defcounter}{0}
\renewcommand{\thedefcounter}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{defcounter}}

\newtcolorbox{definition}[1][]{%
    enhanced,
    before skip=2mm,after skip=2mm, 
    colback=yellow, colframe=red, % Colors
    attach boxed title to top left={xshift=0.3cm,yshift*=-5mm},
    % The titlebox:
    boxed title style={frame code={%
        \path[left color=red,right color=red,
        middle color=red]
        ([xshift=-0mm]frame.north west) -- ([xshift=0mm]frame.north east)
        [rounded corners=0mm]-- ([xshift=0mm,yshift=0mm]frame.north east)
        -- (frame.south east) -- (frame.south west)
        -- ([xshift=0mm,yshift=0mm]frame.north west)
        [sharp corners]-- cycle;
        },interior engine=empty,
    },
    rounded corners,arc=3mm,
    drop fuzzy shadow, % Shadow
    fonttitle=\bfseries, 
    title={\addtocounter{defcounter}{1} \textit{Definition \thedefcounter}\ #1}
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Sample Chapter}

\begin{definition}[Homeomorphism]
    This definition has a title. 
\end{definition}

\begin{definition}
    This definition does NOT have a title.
\end{definition}

\end{document}

Which produces:

How can I get the "Homeomorphism" part of the title to be how I want? I'm thinking a hacky way would be to create some white box over the border and put the optional title there (but then I need a way to detect if there is a title or not).
I also think the \addtocounter{defcounter}{1} in the title is kinda hacky and probably not a good formal solution, so I appreciate it if you have any suggestions as to do the counter in any better way.

Also: yes, I want the counter to reset each chapter, i.e. if the last definition in chapter 1 is 1.9, I want the first in chapter two to be 2.1 (as it is in the MWE).
Edit: Also, I want to create more environments like this with different names and counters (theorem, lemma, example, ansatz, postulate, corollary, etc.). Is there a way to make this process easier by using \newcommand or something to "automate" the process?


tcolorbox has the IfEmptyTF key which you can use to check if the title is empty or not

instead of manually setting the counters, use the auto counter,number within=chapter option to automatically add counters which will reset at the start of a chapter



\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pagecolor}

\pagecolor{green}

\tcbset{
    enhanced,
    top=4mm,
    before skip=2mm,after skip=2mm, 
    colback=\thepagecolor, colframe=red, % Colors
    colbacktitle=\thepagecolor,
    % The titlebox:
    coltitle=red,
    attach boxed title to top left={xshift=3.2cm,yshift=-0.4cm},
    rounded corners,arc=3mm,
    % The "folded paper" in the bottom right corner:
    drop fuzzy shadow, % Shadow
    fonttitle=\bfseries, 
}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=chapter]{definition}[1][]{%
    boxed title style={
      IfEmptyTF={#1}{interior engine=empty}{},
      frame code={%
        \node[fill=red,font=\bfseries\color{white},anchor=east,rounded corners=2mm] at ([xshift=0.45mm]frame.west) {\strut Definition \thetcbcounter:};    
      },
    },
    title={\strut #1}
}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=chapter]{theorem}[1][]{%
    boxed title style={
      IfEmptyTF={#1}{interior engine=empty}{},
      frame code={%
        \node[fill=red,font=\bfseries\color{white},anchor=east,rounded corners=2mm] at ([xshift=0.45mm]frame.west) {\strut Theorem \thetcbcounter:};    
      },
    },
    title={\strut #1}
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Sample Chapter}

\begin{definition}[Homeomorphism]
    This definition has a title. 
\end{definition}

\begin{definition}
    This definition does NOT have a title.
\end{definition}

\begin{theorem}[Homeomorphism]
    This definition has a title. 
\end{theorem}

\end{document}



Nice! Is it possible to make it work for non white backgrounds, like a faint gray or something? Also, with \tcbset what do I do if I have other boxes? Will they be affected?

@Vebjorn Replace white with whatever background colour your page has. If you don't want to change the options globally, you can add them to the definition of each new tcolorbox.

Yes, but if I change the color to, say, yellow, I clearly see a white box under "Homeomorphism", which is not what I want.

@Vebjorn Use the colour of the page

@Vebjorn If you have a new question, please ask a new question

@Vebjorn It is rather rude to edit a question in a way which invalidates existing answers. You should ask a new question.

Ok, sorry, I will. I wasn't clear enough in my question. I wanted it to work with different backgrounds initially. I wanted a "non hacky" solution that would work with different background colors, but that was not clear from my question.
